# Should tag:fread now also be applied to R data.table's fread() (as well as C and PHP)?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-wiki

Should we also use [fread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fread) for R `data.table::fread()`?

The R language's package `data.table` is getting more use, and in particular its `fread` command is ~100x faster than R's `read.csv`, but crashes a lot.

`data.table::fread()` loosely does the same general thing as C and PHP's, but obviously is totally different code. R's fread reads structured tables from textfiles (.CSV, etc.) whereas C's reads any file in general, and no assumptions about structure. I think it's ok to use it (tag wiki would need a slight edit).

One example question (there are several others):

[Error Message: RStudio R Session has stopped working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21195881/error-message-rstudio-r-session-has-stopped-working)

References:
http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fread
http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/data.table/docs/fread

Comment: Why not? C and PHP are also different.

Comment: @Manu: The code at least is rather similar.  Someone looking for an answer about C's `fread` will be able to make some use out of PHP answers, and vice versa.  (Not the specific order/types of args, probably, but the general logic of using it is similar.)  Can this be said for R's version?  I'm actually asking; i don't know.

Comment: I don't know either. But there are already some questions tagged with `r` and `fread`.